# Azure SQL DB: Can I share stored procedures between master DB and all DB's in the server?

Tags: azure, stored-procedures, azure-sql-database

I have an Azure SQL server that contains 15 DBs and it keeps rising every week.
When I create a new DB I need to run several queries for creating a login, user, and assigned roles. All this done using the SQL server admin and the SQL is ran agains the master DB.

I want to automate this entire process.
I was thinking to create a stored procedure that will run all the queries and then I need to run the store procedure.

My problem is: Where do I need to create the store procedure?
I was thinking to create it at the master DB level and share it with all future DBs I will create. Is it possible?
I read that in order to do it I need to name the store procedures with the prefix "sp_".

I tired it and it didn't work.

Thank you for the help, Tal

Answer (score 1):

You can use [elastic jobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/elastic-jobs-overview?view=azuresql) to run those queries on one or a set of existing databases, or newly created databases. Elastic Jobs provide the ability to run one or more T-SQL scripts in parallel, across a number of databases, on a schedule or on-demand.

You can use elastic jobs not only to set them initially, but to later keep them standardize, applying changes to all of them at once when needed. You can run scheduled jobs against any combination of databases: one or more individual databases, all databases on a server, all databases in an elastic pool, or shard map, with the added flexibility to include or exclude any specific database. Jobs can run across multiple servers, multiple pools, and can even run against databases in different subscriptions